# I do not understand why this worker cannot spawn a sub-worker in IE10 HTML5

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10, web-worker, worker

I have a Worker.js file and a Subworker.js file in my Scripts folder.  No problem creating a worker, I can step through its code in the debugger; but when I want that worker to spawn a subworker, it isn't getting created, and I'm unable to step through the subworker code file in the debugger.

```
In myPage.htm script block:
var worker = new Worker("Scripts/Worker.js");   // Succeeds

In Worker.js script file:
var subworker = new Worker("Subworker.js");   //without the folder name  FAILS
```

The IE10 developer tools Network console shows this:

```
URL....................Method...Result..Type.......................Received.......Taken......Initiator
/Scripts/Worker.js.....GET......200.....application/x-javascript...1.00KB..........<1ms......webworker
/Scripts/Subworker.js..GET......404.....text/html..................2.50KB..........239.29s...webworker
```

EDIT: Found the answer to the 404 error although still unable to instantiate the subworker:

```
         var subworker = new Worker("..Subworker.js");
```

EDIT2:  Also found that the following trick to cause the current version of a script to be used generates a 400 error:

```
         var subworker = new Worker("..Subworker.js?version=2.0");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm in about the same boat.

My plan is to load a subworker from another doamin or `file://` protocol because you cannot load one directly from a regular js script. I still need to test this, but I know that `Workers/SharedWorkers` are not subject to the normal **Cross-Origin Restriction Policy**, except** for when you're trying to load one (and hopefully only when doing this from a `window` script).

Another method is to use `window.postMessage` to forward messages to a Worker that it has created in the other `window`.

Alternatively, for my specific needs I am considering running a headless browser locally, a CDN, or a `localhost` "forever-server" with `CORS` enabled -- but this most likely still requires a `window.postMessage()`.

Hope this helps, Tim!

Post back if you find an answer, eh?